# Regression coefficients for centered predictor variables: One unit increase *as well as* decrease?

Tags: regression

I have a question on how to interpret coefficients in a regression analysis:

I'm doing a (logistic) regression analysis with a mean centered (continuous) predictor (where the 0 value has no meaning). With non-centered predictors, I would interpret the coefficient for the predictor as the change in the outcome variable for one unit *increase* in the predictor variable; adding one unit of the predictor variable is the only thing that makes sense, since the level for this variable is set to 0.

However, when I have *centered predictors*, can the coefficient for the predictor be interpreted as the change in the outcome for a predictor variable unit *increase* and a unit *decrease*, that is, in both directions away from the the mean? -- Obviously, half of my data consists of observations that have lower than average values on the outcome variable, and I'm interested in having meaningful coefficients for these as well ... (I can't find any answer to this, neither on the YouTube channels I use for statistics learning, nor in my (regrettably only 5) statistics books.)

(See the attached screenshots for an example: OLS regressions from the `mtcars` package in `R` (with `mpg` (miles per gallon) as outcome and `wt` (weight in 1000 lbs) as predictor, mean centered in the bottom screenshot.)

[image: Raw predictor scores]

[image: Mean centered predictor scores]

Comment: because you fit an intercept, you can see in your example, 1 unit increase in centeredWT would correspond to -5 unit decrease in the y variable

Comment: centering does not affect your coefficient in this case. interpretation stays the same

Comment: Hi, @StupidWolf! Yes, 1 unit increase in centeredWT is fine, but what about observations that are *lower* than the mean, i.e., a unit *decrease*? How can we figure out any regression coefficient for them? -- Is it simply the *negative* of the regression coefficient associated with the one unit increase?